# regular expression for numeric range in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to find numeric range in the format "number-number". the number should be in the range 0-3000. so I came up with this regular expression

```
match = re.search(r'^[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',sentence)
```

When I ran the program I wanted to extract only 56-900 in the sentence but the program extracted other numbers also like 2016, CLP2012 etc.. I wanted to extract only numbers that have "-" in between them. What is wrong in my pattern.

Comment: You should use `"[0-9]+-[0-9]+"`.

Comment: The `|` operator has least priority, so even e.g. `[1-9][0-9]` is an accepted pattern: you should parenthesize the two parts before and after the hyphen. Also, a more compact formulation should exist.

Comment: Why not `"[123]\d{0,3}"` (or `"[0-3]\d{0,3}"` to include 0's)?

Answer (score 6):

### Use the python package [regex_engine](https://pypi.org/project/regex-engine/) for generate regular expressions for numerical ranges

You can install this package by using pip

> pip install regex-engine

```
from regex_engine import generator

generate = generator()

regex = generate.numerical_range(0,3000)

print(regex)
```

> ^([0-9]|[2-8][0-9]|1[0-9]|9[0-9]|[2-8][0-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]|10[0-9]|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|[2-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9][0-9]|10[1-9][0-9]|100[0-9]|300[0-0])$

You can also generate regexes for floating point and negative ranges

```
from regex_engine import generator

generate = generator()

regex1 = generate.numerical_range(5,89)
regex2 = generate.numerical_range(81.78,250.23)
regex3 = generate.numerical_range(-65,12)
```

Comment: Weird package. It worked really well, but for whatever reason it adds `^` at the beginning and `$`, so that python's `re.search` fails on substrings...

Comment: You can remove those using the replace() method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match ranges of integers, you need to protect the matches with r"\b" (begin/end of string):

```
>>> import re

>>> text = "2016, CLP2012 56-900 3000-3000 4000-4000 123-123 0-0"
>>> re.findall(r"\b\d+-\d+\b", text)
['56-900', '3000-3000', '4000-4000', '123-123', '0-0']
```

If you want to match only integers from 0 to 3000, you need a more precise RegEx, like this:

```
>>> r = r"(?:3000|[1-2]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d|\d)"
>>> re.findall(r"\b" + r + "-" + r + r"\b", text)
['56-900', '3000-3000', '123-123', '0-0']
```

Comment: I think '^' for begin and '$' for end is better.

Comment: @scriptboy: No, `^`(or `$`) mean "begin" (or "end") of **string**. Not "begin" (or "end") or **word** (which is matched by `\w+`)

Answer (score 0):

This code extract just a true range `x-y`  and  `x< y <= 3000`

```
sentence = 'test 69 example 55-66 example 77-44 example 999-3001 example'

for word in re.findall('\d+-\d+', sentence):
    l = word.split('-')
    if int(l[0])< int(l[1]) <= 3000:
        word
```

Output for this example :

```
'55-66'
```